# Discrepancy on Rep Leagues page

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

I recently noticed a discrepancy on the bottom of the right sidebar on [the Rep Leagues page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/month/meta-stackoverflow/2013-12-01).
[image: Freehand Red Circles FTW!]

Asterisks 1 and 2 point to paragraph 4, which states

> *users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues

This appears to apply to the **Reputation Change** section.

However, this clearly does not apply to the **Total Reputation** section, as evidenced by all 91,285 MSO users being shown in row 3.

While nothing is clearly *lying*, asterisk 2 is *misleading*. I would suggest that asterisk 2 be removed.